# Facebook Session.StatusCallback never get called in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

I'm developing an app that's have a FB authorization, I have a main activity(fragment activity) which provides to user to login by his name/password or by FB, when he click's the "login through FB" button he'll be moved to FB-auth fragment and now it works **pretty good** BUT somehow the *Session.StatusCallback* never get called, I've noticed this when I've tried to get User-data from FB. So for what reason it can be?

Here is my FBFragment code:

```
public class FragmentLoginFacebook extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = FragmentLoginFacebook.class.getSimpleName();

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private final List<String> permissions;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_for_fragments, container, false);
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }

    return view;
}

public FragmentLoginFacebook() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status", "email", "user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "publish_actions");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is " + user.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

        //--> Never get Called
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

    }
        //Cause i'd never seen a Login/Logout logcat messages from onSessionStateChange
};
```

}

**UPD:**
My activity class

```
public class ActivityLogin extends FragmentActivity {
private Fragment mCurrentFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_fragments);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mCurrentFragment = new FragmentLoginMain();
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("login") == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentLayout, mCurrentFragment, "login").commit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**UPD#2**
By **Roger Alien** answer I've added in Activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && (requestCode & 0xFFFF) == 0xFACE) { // if it was request to authorize facebook user
                for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) { // transmit to all fragments? is it safe..? // TODO check logic
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode & 0xffff, resultCode, data);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

STILL NOT WORKING!

Comment: The error you have is because when you open the session, you're passing in JUST the activity, rather than passing in the fragment as well (there's an openActiveSession method where you can also pass in the fragment). If you don't pass in the fragment, then the result won't go to your fragment's onActivityResult, and will only go to the activity's onActivityResult.